# Get new state from redux storage with useSelector returns initial state in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have just for several reasons **migrated from** the old style of redux (**pre 2019**) which used case, switch etc. The redux store gets updated as it should which i can see in the TextInput for example but when trying to use the selected value from redux store elsewhere inside the screen function it seems to **initial state** and **not the updated one**. Shortened code below and any help would be greatly appriciated.

**redux/slices/auth.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const initialState = {
    email: "",
}

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'userAuth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setEmail: (state, action) => {
            state.email = action.payload.email;
        }
    }
});

export const { setEmail } = authSlice.actions;

export const selectEmail = (state) => state.userAuth.email;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

**redux/store.js**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import authSlice from './slices/auth'

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        userAuth: authSlice,
    },
})
```

**screens/LoginScreen.js**

```
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import { selectEmail, setEmail } from '../../redux/slices/auth';


function LoginScreen({navigation}) {
    const _email = useSelector(selectEmail);

    const onEmailButtonPress = async () => {
        console.log("Begin sign in: Email");
        // GETS INITIAL STATE AND NOT UPDATED ONE 
        if (_email == null || _email == 0 || _email == ""){
            console.log(_email);
            return;
        }
    }

        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Login with e-mail</Text>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Enter e-mail address"
                    placeholderTextColor={'#000'}
                    keyboardType="email-address"
                    onChangeText={(value) => dispatch(setEmail(value))}
                    maxLength={128}
                    value={_email} // SHOWS UPDATED STATE
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => onEmailButtonPress()}
                >
                    <Text>Continue</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default LoginScreen;
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(true);
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        {/*<PersistGate persistor={persistor}>*/}
          <LoadingScreen />
        {/*</PersistGate>*/}
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the reducer you are reading `action.payload.email` but in the component you are dispatching `setEmail(value)`.

That's not consistent, or you read in the reducer `action.payload` or you dispatch in the component `setEmail({email: value})`

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally missed that.